# Hibernate Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement with Postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm having a little trouble with my entities (using Spring-boot). I just can't seem to understand what might be the problem. What might be the reason that hibernate does not find the relations between the entities?

I am getting the following **exceptions** when trying to run the application:

```
Error executing DDL "alter table order_barcode drop constraint FK16yppq17qkt9vaiw536c468xq" via JDBC Statement
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "order_barcode" does not exist
Error executing DDL "alter table "orders" drop constraint FK7nkj808174vaoen3hn8lp39i6" via JDBC Statement
ERROR: relation "orders" does not exist
ERROR: relation "order_ticket" does not exist
```

**Entities**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="\"orders\"")
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Order {

    public enum OrderStatus {
     
        INITIALIZED("initialized"),
        COMPLETE("complete"),
        FAILED("failed");

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

  
    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private OrderStatus status;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    private Set<OrderTicket> tickets;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private OrderPayment payment;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class OrderBarcode {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private Long id;

    private String barcode;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class OrderPayment {

    public enum PaymentStatus {
        INITIALIZED("initialized"),
        AUTHORIZED("authorized"),

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private PaymentStatus status;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class OrderTicket {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private Long id;

    private Long templateId;
   
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ticket_id")
    private Set<OrderBarcode> barcodes;
}
```

**Configuration**

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test
    username: ${DATABASE_USERNAME}
    password: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
  jpa:
    hibernate:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect
      ddl-auto: create-drop
      # ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate:
       connection:
          characterEncoding: utf-8
          CharSet: utf-8
          useUniCode: true
       show-sql: false
        hbm2ddl:
          import_files: sql/import.sql
          import_files_sql_extractor: org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem with an entity "User" and it turned out renaming it to "UserDTO" helped. The same was true for your "Order" which errored for me until I changed the name to "OrderDTO".

There's actually a number of reserved words that cannot be used as table names: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html

Answer (score 0):

can you try to add @Table annotation on each table that doesn't exists ?

```
@Table(name = "ORDER",schema="xxxxx")
```

Hibernate will drop your shema then create it at boot as you set spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: create-drop

Comment: sadly , that dosen't solve the problem getting the same error messages

Comment: I would also consider to sepatate your lombok DTOs from Spring data JPA entities.

Comment: I've now tested if with ddl-auto:update  and got 0 Errors :?

Comment: well that's clear - then he starts and drops it afterwards, that means it goes first and then no longer